# Package pagenote with tex4ebook does not result in satisfying ebook links

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook, pagenote

I need the package `pagenote` to get endnotes with pagenumbers refering in the print version of the pdf with pdflatex. With `tex4ebook` I need to get this pagenotes accordingly, but without pagenumbers, and with hyperlinks to get from the epub text content to the endnote/pagenote at the end of the epub, and vice versa. In addition it should be possible to get into bibliography when cited an author.

With the follow MWE I get good result for the pdf print version. But when converting it into epub with tex4ebook, the links between endnote/pagenote in text document and at the end of the epub document lacks functionality and the pagenumbers are shown like in the print version pdf file.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Philosophy}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\usepackage{csquotes}

\begin{document}
\section{Beginn einer Freundschaft}
    "`Ein zitierter Satz eines Autors."'\footcite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
\section{Fortsetzung einer Freundschaft}
    "`Ein weiterer, zitierter Satz."'\footfullcite{sigfridsson}
\clearpage
\section{Kür einer Freundschaft}
    Etwas mit Fußnote/Pagenote.\footnote{A footnote that should become a pagenote, respectively a hyperref at the end of the ebook/epub file.}

\clearpage
\printnotes

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

What should be done to get in the ebook a hyperref functionality for the pagenotes?

**Edit 1:**

Option `hyperfootnotes` in package `hyperref` added and package `csquotes`. But still no hyperfootnotes/pagenotes in epub visible. Instead the following warning during tex4ebook run:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Patching footnotes failed.
(biblatex)                Footnote detection will not work.
```

Does anybody know what to do?

**Edit 2**

The following has been successfully with pdflatex compiled after answer 1. When using the package `pagenote` (with pagenote.4ht file by Michal in answer 1) with `bibliography` **and** `indexing` an `Undefined control sequence` occurs if it is compiled with
`tex4ebook -a debug -c configfile.cfg -e buildfile.mk4 -m index Sourcefile.tex`

The LaTeX file `Sourcefile.tex` shows like this as a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\fi
\makeindex
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,hyperindex=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Philosophy}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{\addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\noindent\textsc{\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\large #1}}}
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Anmerkungen und Verweise}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\section{Beginn einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Beginn einer Freundschaft}
    "`Ein zitierter Satz eines Autors.\index{Autor}"'\footcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\section{Fortsetzung einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Fortsetzung einer Freundschaft}
    "`Ein weiterer, zitierter Satz.\index{Satz}"'\footfullcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\section{Kür einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Kür einer Freundschaft}
    Etwas\index{Etwas} mit Fußnote/Pagenote.\footnote{A footnote that should become a pagenote}

\clearpage
\printnotes

\clearpage
\printindex

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And this is the problem:

```
Kapitel 1.
(./Testdocument_pagenote.ent
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 ...Ct \relax \let \prOteCt \relax \Protect \gl
                                                  :removeindenttrue \unhbox ...
```

Without indexing the answer 1 here works best with tex4ebook. What can be done?

Comment: hyperref cannot help you, this will need separate configuration for this package. I will post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `pagenote` package is not supported by TeX4ht yet, but it is quite easy to add basic support. Try this configuration file, `pagenote.4ht`:

```
% patch commands that print note numbers, so we can add links
\NewConfigure{notenumintext}{2}
\def\:tempa#1{\a:notenumintext\o:notenumintext:{#1}\b:notenumintext}
\HLet\notenumintext\:tempa

\NewConfigure{notenuminnotes}{2}
% we must save the note id in \:currentnoteid, to make it available in \Configure{notenuminnotes}
\def\:tempa#1{\def\:currentnoteid{#1}\a:notenuminnotes\o:notenuminnotes:{#1}\b:notenuminnotes}
\HLet\notenuminnotes\:tempa

% to remove the page numbers
\HLet\pageinnotes\:gobble

% default configuration
\Configure{notenumintext}{\Link{pagenote\thepagenote}{pagenote-bk\thepagenote}}{\EndLink}
\Configure{notenuminnotes}{\Link{pagenote-bk\:currentnoteid}{pagenote\:currentnoteid}}{\EndLink}

\Hinput{pagenote}

\endinput
```

This configuration adds links to footnotes and back to text from footnotes.

**Edit:**

With the updated TeX file, you need to use `\protect` for `\noindent` in your `\addtonotesnewcommand`. To prevent the spurious `Kapitel 0` text, you also need to update the counter that `pagenote` keeps to detect chapter changes:

```
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{%
  \ifpnhaschapter%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else%
      \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else%
      \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\textsc{\large #1}}%
}
```

This is the full TeX file:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[xindy,noautomatic]{imakeidx}
\else
\usepackage[]{imakeidx}
\fi
\makeindex
\ifdefined\HCode
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=true,hyperindex=true,
pdfauthor={Autor},
pdftitle={Titel},
pdfkeywords={Philosophy}]{hyperref}
\else\fi
\usepackage[sortlocale=auto,bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authortitle-ticomp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{%
  \ifpnhaschapter%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else%
      \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else%
      \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
  \addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\textsc{\large #1}}%
}
% \newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{\addtonotes{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Anmerkungen und Verweise}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\begin{document}

\section{Beginn einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Beginn einer Freundschaft}
    "`Ein zitierter Satz eines Autors.\index{Autor}"'\footcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\section{Fortsetzung einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Fortsetzung einer Freundschaft}
    "`Ein weiterer, zitierter Satz.\index{Satz}"'\footfullcite{sigfridsson}

\clearpage
\section{Kür einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Kür einer Freundschaft}
    Etwas\index{Etwas} mit Fußnote/Pagenote.\footnote{A footnote that should become a pagenote}

\clearpage
\printnotes

\clearpage
\printindex

\clearpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

And backlinks from the notes page:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Michal. I will try it later in the evening. But it seems that you have solved the task. Is it planed to implement this functionality in `TeX4ht` depending on loaded package `pagenote`?

Comment: @Thomkrates yes, I will add it

Comment: Thank you, it works like intended for the epub. - But in the pdf the "Kapitel 0" in the "Notes" is not necessary. With `\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{}` it is not possible to "delete" it. I use my own definition of `\addtonotes` to have separate section titles dividing the continuous pagenotes. But the "Kapitel 0" remains. It seems that it comes from `\printnotes`. But how to suppress "Kapitel 0" in pdf file?

Comment: I added Edit 2 to my question; here indexing is added, but with error message of undefined control sequence when running tex4ebook. What needs to be done to fix this?

Comment: @Thomkrates the error is not caused by the indexing, but by the `\addtonotesnewcommand` command. I've updated my answer with a fix.

Comment: Ok, thank you Michal. I have read the last days about the `\protect` tag in relationship with a tex4ebook run of tex-source code, but I did not unterstand the meaning of it. So I omitted this. But I will try it this evening. Thank you again. - And what about the `"Kaptitel 0"` displaying in the epub in the Notes? I do not understand that too.

Comment: @Thomkrates I see `Kaptitel 0` even in PDF, so there must be some issue in your docuemnt

Comment: Ok., I see it too. I tried the last days a bit to get it right, but I did not find the answer up to now. I will come back to this point the next days. Thank you Michal!

Comment: @Thomkrates I've found the source of this problem, see the edited anser.

Comment: Thank you, Michal. Again you solved the problem excellently. It is a great pleasure for me. Thank you very much. - Will this be included in the pagenote package? It seems that since 2009 no new update came up.

Comment: @Thomkrates the links to pagenotes and backlinks are already included in TeX4ht sources, so they should be available in TeX Live 2023 soon.

Comment: @Thomkrates could you please accept my answers? This is necessary to unmark these questions as unanswered. Thanks :)

Comment: Of cource, I needed to know how, but found it. Thank you again.