# Package pagenote works insufficent and puts a 'chapter' at an unintended position in Notes

Tags: pagenote

When using the package `pagenote` with the following MWE, the pdflatex output contains an `Kapitel` (chapter) text in the pagenotes (Notes=Anmerkungen und Verweise), which seems to be at wrong position and is not possible to omit by `\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{}`...

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\let\footnote=\pagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{\addtonotes{\large\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\textsc{\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip} #1}}}
\renewcommand*{\notesname}{Anmerkungen und Verweise}
\renewcommand*{\chaptername}{}% This seems not to work correctly!
\renewcommand*{\thechapter}{}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\section*{\notesname}}

\begin{document}

\section{Beginn einer Freundschaft}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection. Beginn einer Freundschaft}

    A sentence with a footnote that becomes a pagenote.\footnote{Some text in a footnote/pagenote}
    
\clearpage
\printnotes

\end{document}
```

Does anybody has experience with the pagenote package and can suggest some ideas to solve the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem and question has been answered by user and developer michal.h21 in:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680395/292824