# How to generate an epub with linked endnotes?

Tags: memoir, endnotes, tex4ebook, enotez

My MWE generates a PDF with links from the ref to the endnote and from the endnote to the ref. When I convert my TeX to epub using `tex4ebook main.tex -o main.epub` I lose the links.

How can I generate an epub from my LaTeX that has linked endnotes? It's for a book and I'm open to changing up my workflow, including converting the main matter to markdown, using a tool other than `tex4ebook`, or using another packages for endnotes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{enotez}
\setenotez{backref=true}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    Some sample text.\endnote{And a sample endnote}
    \printendnotes
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified the code for a similar package, `pagenote`, for which [I wrote support not long ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/680395/2891). See the linked answer for more details, the basic idea is the same - I added some TeX4ht hooks to insert links to the list of notes and back.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewConfigure{enotezmark}{2}
\protected\def\:tempa #1#2{\def\:currentnoteid{#1}\a:enotezmark\o:enotez_write_mark:nn:{#1}{#2}\b:enotezmark}
\HLet\enotez_write_mark:nn\:tempa

\NewConfigure{enotezback}{2}
\protected\def\:tempa#1{\def\:currentnoteid{#1}\a:enotezback\o:enotez_write_list_number:n:{#1}\b:enotezback}
\HLet\enotez_write_list_number:n\:tempa

\Configure{enotezmark}{\Link{enotez\:currentnoteid}{enotez-bk\:currentnoteid}}{\EndLink}
\Configure{enotezback}{\Link{enotez-bk\:currentnoteid}{enotez\:currentnoteid}\HCode{<sup>}}{\HCode{</sup>}\EndLink}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't suppose you could change the format of the ref number in the Notes section to not be raised? The raised ref number on the body of the text is awesome but in the endnotes, shouldn't it be the same as the endnote text? So, `1. And a sample endnote`? Alternatively, getting rid of the dot after the ref number would work, too. The raised number with the period after it looks odd to me.

Comment: @buttonsrtoys I think you can just remove `\HCode{<sup>}` and `\HCode{</sup>}` from `\Configure{enotezback}`.

Comment: That sounds perfect. The above code isn't in my `tex4ebook.cfg` file to make this change. How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: @buttonsrtoys ah, I see more issues now, there is also wrong spacing. I've fixed that in TeX4ht sources, so it should be available in TL soon.

Answer (score 0):

I saw [here](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ebook/issues/91#issuecomment-1019450401) that someone got linked endnotes working with tex4ebook by rolling their own with `\label` and `\ref`. I wrote the mwe below to do this which creates the commands `noteref` and `noteitem`. I added a tappable arrow to the endnote to return to the ref. I need to add a conditional to the mwe to remove the arrow when compiling for print. I'd also like to add a period after the number in the enumerated list, but am not sure how without also added the period to the superscript number. I'll update the mwe when I get these added.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{dummy}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\noteref}[1]{\textsuperscript{\ref{itm:#1}\label{#1ref}}}
\newcommand{\noteitem}[1]{\item\label{itm:#1}\hyperref[#1ref]{$\nwarrow$}}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\mprime}{\ensuremath{'}}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{Chapter 1}
This is really noteworthy.\noteref{first}
\chapter*{Chapter 2}
This, too, is noteworthy.\noteref{second}
\chapter*{Chapter 3}
This is also noteworthy.\noteref{third}
\chapter*{Notes}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textnormal{\arabic*}]
    \noteitem{first} This is the first endnote.
    \noteitem{second} This is the second endnote.
    \noteitem{third} This is the third endnote.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```