# \pagenote in \section with undesired result when using \addtonote (or \addtonotenewcommand)

Tags: pagenote

With the following MWE the undesired result in `Notes` shows as follows:

1. A "Chapter 0" is added in `Notes`, and
2. the pagenotes are postponed and not ordered correctly with `\addtonotes` (or `\addtonotesnewcommand`).
   How could this be solved?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[continuous,page]{pagenote}
\makepagenote
\newcommand*{\addtonotesnewcommand}[1]{%
    \ifpnhaschapter%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{chapter}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{chapter}}%
    \fi%
    \else%
    \ifnum\value{pnotesavechap}=\value{section}\else%
    \setcounter{pnotesavechap}{\value{section}}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
    \addtonotes{\vspace*{0.7\baselineskip}\protect\noindent\vspace*{0.35\baselineskip}\textsc{\large #1}}%
}% by Michal H.
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{First section: with pagenote\protect\pagenote{Pagenote for first section}}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection\ Pagenote title text for first section}

\section{Second Section: without pagenote}

\section{Third section: with pagenote\protect\pagenote{Pagenote for third section}}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection\ Pagenote title text for third section}

\section{Fourth Section: without pagenote}

\section{Fifth section: with pagenote\protect\pagenote{Pagenote for fifth section}}
\addtonotesnewcommand{\thesection\ Pagenote title text for fifth section}

\renewcommand*{\notedivision}{\chapter*{\notesname}}
\printnotes

\end{document}
```

Thank you for support.

Comment: Please link to relevant previous questions/answers.

Comment: Links do not help in this case. This is a totally new case and problem.

Comment: @Thomkrates Well, but they do, though... You are including some code there which says "by Michal H.", a search suggests that this code is meant to make things work with `tex4ht` which is not an explicit requirement in this question. It is also not obvious what this code is meant to do out of context. So, from the perspective of someone who might be able / willing to help, this is a sort of flag that tells us this is likely to be an unproductive exchange. So, if cfr gave you some helpful advice, don't just dismiss it.

Comment: Sorry. I found the following link from spring this year: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/680320/package-pagenote-with-tex4ebook-does-not-result-in-satisfying-ebook-links